# How to fetch data from MySQL database and Load it to Spinner?

Tags: android

I have my school project where I need to fetch values from MySQL database and display it to Spinner in Android.
I am using Android Studio and Volley Library for the networking operation but confused how to achieve this thing. 
I'll appreciate your help. Thank You :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to first create a php script that will print the data of your mysql database in json format.. Here I am showing you an example lets see this is my database 
[image: MySQL Database]

Now suppose I need to load all the username of this table to android's spinner. So this is the php script that will give me the data in json format

```
<?php 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM students";

require_once('dbConnect.php');

$r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$result = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){
    array_push($result,array(
        'username'=>$row['username'],
        'name'=>$row['name'],
        'course'=>$row['course'],
        'session'=>$row['session']
    ));
}

echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));

mysqli_close($con);
```

The above php code will give the following json

```
{"result":[{"username":"faiz","name":"Faiz Khan","course":"BCA","session":"2014-2017"},{"username":"belal","name":"Belal Khan","course":"MCA","session":"2015-2018"},{"username":"ramiz","name":"Ramiz Khan","course":"MBA","session":"2015-2017"},{"username":"zafar","name":"Zafar Khan","course":"MBA","session":"2014-2016"}]}
```

Now android code will be MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
private Spinner spinner;
private ArrayList<String> students;
private JSONArray result;
private TextView textViewName;
private TextView textViewCourse;
private TextView textViewSession;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    students = new ArrayList<String>();
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    textViewName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
    textViewCourse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCourse);
    textViewSession = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSession);
    getData();
}

private void getData(){
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest("your php script address",
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    JSONObject j = null;
                    try {
                        j = new JSONObject(response);
                        result = j.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);
                        getStudents(result);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void getStudents(JSONArray j){
    for(int i=0;i<j.length();i++){
        try {
            JSONObject json = j.getJSONObject(i);
            students.add(json.getString(Config.TAG_USERNAME));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, students));
}
}
```

Source [Android Spinner Example with MySQL Database](http://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-spinner-example-to-load-json-using-volley/)

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridView;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Ourteam extends Fragment {
    OurteamAdapter madap;
    GridView l1;
    ArrayList<OurteamModel> llist;
    JsonHelper Jobj;
    JSONObject obj = null;
    Button close,btnhome,btnlogin,btnback;
    String Id,s_id,AdvocateId;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.ourteam, null);
        l1 = (GridView)v. findViewById(R.id.ListView1);

        Process pro = new Process();
        pro.execute(new String[]{"ourteam.php"});
        return v;
    }

    private class Process extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>
    {
        ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            dialog.setMessage("Loading Please wait...");
            dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
            dialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... Url)
        {
            for(String Url1 : Url)
            {
                Jobj = new JsonHelper();
                obj = Jobj.MakeJsonCall(Url1, 2);
                try
                {
                    llist = new ArrayList<OurteamModel>();
                    JSONArray JArr = obj.getJSONArray("record");


                    for(int i=0;i<JArr.length();i++)
                    {
                        JSONObject dObj = JArr.getJSONObject(i);
                        llist.add(new OurteamModel(dObj.getString("t_id"), dObj.getString("t_name"),JsonHelper.team.toString() +dObj.getString("t_image"),dObj.getString("t_content")  ));

                    }
                }
                catch (JSONException e)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return true;
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result)
        {
            madap = new OurteamAdapter(getActivity(), llist);

            l1.setAdapter(madap);

            for(OurteamModel mm : llist)
            {
                mm.LoadImage(madap);
            }
            l1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                        Intent i=new Intent(getActivity(),FragmentMaster.class);
                        i.putExtra("frgNo", "11");


                   i.putExtra("category_id",llist.get(position).getServiceId());
                        startActivity(i);

                }
            });
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1. [Read the Spinner class documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html)
2. Query your Database
3. Fetch the results
4. Encode the data into JSON format
5. Request and parse results in your app
6. Populate a list array for the spinner
7. Set the adapter on your spinner